# Custom menu as admin menu

Tags: routes

Is there a module that take a custom menu and show it like [Admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu)?

I want to create my custom menu and then display it like admin menu (only for some roles).

I've tried some modules but:

- [Admin menu](http://drupal.org/project/admin_menu) does not allow to select which menu should be displayed, and however I want to display default menu for Administrator and a custom menu for "editors" and other custom roles
- [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish) or [Nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) does not allow to place the menu in top of page, like Admin menu does

Another solution could be a module that place a block in top of page, fixed, so I could use a "simple" superfish menu, but I have not find something like this.

The main question is that I can't use the "default" management menu, but a custom menu.

Comment: Feature request for admin menu module [posted in issue queue](https://drupal.org/node/2080145).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You want [Admin menu source](https://drupal.org/project/admin_menu_source). It allows you to configure each role with a menu as the source for admin_menu.

Answer (score 3):

[Webmaster menu](https://drupal.org/project/webmaster_menu) generates a toolbar (aka dropdown menu) from a custom menu. Visible only to selected roles.

[image]

> This module makes it quick to place a custom menu as a toolbar.
>
> One use-case is creating an administration menu for the webmaster(s)
>   of a site (a "webmaster" here means: the person actually working with
>   the site - creating content etc). Common tasks vary from site to site,
>   hence it is useful to be able to structure the webmaster menu to
>   reflect the daily needs of the webmaster.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Block Class Styles](http://drupal.org/project/block_class_styles) module:

1. Create a menu block using [Menu block](http://drupal.org/project/menu_block), [Superfish](http://drupal.org/project/superfish), [Nice menus](http://drupal.org/project/nice_menus) or similar.
2. In [Block Class Styles](http://drupal.org/project/block_class_styles) define style with:

   ```
   position: fixed;
   top: 0;
   z-index: 999;
   width: auto;
   ```
3. Select that style for a block with your menu.

Same can be done with [Block Class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class), if you are willing to provide CSS properties for fixed menu class in your theme or custom module CSS file.

Note: Admin Menu module sets width as `auto`, but it might require some adjusting with menus rendered by other modules.